# Why does this throw an error using node.js in linux XTerm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

Why does this throw an error using node.js in linux XTerm?

```
console.log("What is the equation?");
var a = window.prompt("A = ");
var b = window.prompt("B = ");
var c = window.prompt("C = ");
```

Comment: Probably because Node doesn't have a `window`, nor a prompt, it's not a browser.

Comment: What do I need to use then

Comment: There is actually a prompt package https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input

Comment: ^ There's that, not that I see why a terminal window should be able to popup prompts, but whatever.